# How to set Cursor to Busy mode in Qt?

Tags: qt4

However when I set cursor from style sheet or from code,

QApplication::setOverrideCursor(Qt::WaitCursor);

QApplication::restoreOverrideCursor(); // for restoring

It works fine with QT Creator.But it isn't working with QWS Server. When it comes to the board, mouse pointer isn't changing. I want to give a busy mouse until a page loading is completed. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a solution..

I just called process events fn after setting the mouse pointer so that the code was immediately executed n  I got the busy mouse pointer till the page finished loading.

QCoreApplication::processEvents();

Thankz..!! ;)

Comment: A word of caution - call processEvents(); with no arguments. 
When I called processEvents(QEventLoop::ExcludeUserInputEvents) wait cursor didn't appear.